# PHP auto logout after session timout on mobile devices

Tags: php, mobile, session-timeout

I am sure someone has run across this issue before, I just haven't been able to find anything on it anywhere.  Anyway here is the scenario.

I have a PHP website that a user will login, then their account id is set as a session variable, then once they are in it basically acts as a single page app.  The session account id is for tracking their activities as they do different things throughout the app.

The site will be accessed primarily on mobile devices.  I have PHP that sets the session timeout length, then using JS, gives them a popup warning a couple minutes before the timeout ends.  Then after the end of the timeout, using a meta refresh, it redirects them back to the login page.

On a desktop, this all works like it is supposed to.  On mobile, it is behaving differently.  On a mobile device, a user may login, do some stuff on a page, then without logging out, put their phone in their pocket and not come back to it for a couple hours.  When they open up the browser it keeps them on the page they were on, but the JS was obviously not running during the time their phone was sleeping, or whatever else they were doing in the interim. The meta refresh as well also does not work as expected, but the session is still timed out.  So when they open the app back up, and try to do stuff, I am getting errors in the DB saying that id cannot be empty.

I can use ajax to check if their session still exists on every click of a button, but for speed of the app I would prefer not to do that.

Has anyone else ran into this and found a solution for automatically logging out people on single page apps viewed on a mobile device?

Comment: you may check the logon status every 5 minutes or so

Comment: That would be something you want to do in the app itself. On iOS, the app has a `applicationDidEnterBackground` callback  that will be invoked by the iOS after the app goes to background. You want to snuff your session there (alternately, `applicationWillResignActive`). Must have equivalent for Android.

Comment: But are the applicationDidEnterBackground  and applicationWillResignActive things I can access with PHP or javascript, or are those native app functions?

Comment: @ormoz - but how do I check the logon status when their phone is asleep, or otherwise not using the site?  That is the problem I currently have, the scripts I have to do handle stuff dont' seem to be running when the user is not actively using the site.

Comment: you can store the last time that session was checked in a variable, then when the user comes back, compare this time with current time and if it is more than 5 min., redirect to login page.

Comment: Let me give that a shot.